# "Moderator for" vs. "moderator of"

Tags: differences, prepositions

In OAAD, there's an example  for the entry *moderator*:

> moderators **of** online discussion groups

But I've seen the preposition **for** used in that context by native speakers too. Are they both correct? Or does it have something to do with different dialects?

Searching Google yields the following result:

- *Moderator for*: About 1,980,000 results
- *Moderator of*: About 6,000,000 results

So, the preposition of is more common. Is that the only difference?

Comment: English prepositions aren't always meaningful, and in some expressions, it's possible to substitute without changing the meaning. British and American English don't always use the same prepositions: _at the weekend_ vs. _on/during/over the weekend_, e.g. More important with the phrase "X is {a/the} moderator {for/of} this site" is the article: _the_ means there's only one, but _a_ means there are at least two. I don't think it's possible to make any reasonable inference about the number of moderators based on the usage of _of_ or _for_. I could be wrong, though.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that "Moderator for" is referencing the main or only moderator for a site, while "Moderator of" indicates that this is just one of several moderators at a site.

Answer (score 0):

I used to be a moderator **for** the site boards.ie

When I was, I was moderator **of** the Paganism, English, Programming, and Sex & Sexuality forums.

The first statement expresses the relationship that rôle had to the site. The second, the relationship that rôle had to particular forums.

The two could overlap. For a while I had responsibilities relating to the entirety of the site, so it would have been correct both to say I was a moderator *for* the site, and a moderator *of* the site.